# How to draw weight on DiGraph through using write_dot?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, networkx

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import write_dot
import pylab
lst = []
G = nx.DiGraph()
nodes = int(input("Enter a number of nodes: "))- 1
for i in range(nodes):
    G.add_node(nodes)
transitions=[]
for i in range(int(input("Enter a number of transitions: "))):
    frm = int(input("Enter from: "))
    to = int(input("Enter to:"))
    wght = int(input("Enter a w:"))
    transitions.append((frm,to,wght))
G.add_weighted_edges_from(transitions,edge_labels=True)
labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'weight')
pos=nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos,edge_labels=labels)
write_dot(G,'graph.dot')
```

I want to create something like a state-diagram of Finite automato but the problem is that i can not represent weight on diagram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use graphviz library rather than networkx
    import graphviz